# Eclipse templates

Tags: php, eclipse, templates

I am using Eclipse Kepler on Ubuntu and was curious how to get templates defined in Preferences->PHP->Editor->Templates to show up on the top of the auto complete list. For example when I type "class" the template for the class is on the bottom of the auto complete drop down, how to I get it to show up on the top of the list?

Also there is a perspective view under Window->Show View->Other->General->Templates, I assume that this is supposed to be a list of templates available but when I show it, the tab contents are blank. Is there something that I have to set to get the list?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: PDT is not supporting Templates view. Your Templates view may come from JDT. When you opened the Java editor, the view will show available templates for Java.

Comment: atlanto, Thanks I was afraid it was going to be something like that. Do you know if there is any way to push the php templates onto the top of the auto complete list?